# Broken pipe issue happens immediately after returning 404

Tags: tomcat, spring-webflux, reactive

I have three services A, B and C. A uses mono zip to call both B and C with timeout 2s. In the happy path, the call to B and C all succeed, and A would aggregate the result which I don’t see broken pipe issue. Only when B or C returns error like 404 entity not found which takes like 150ms, I could see an immediate broken pipe error in the log after it. Does any genius have any ideas on this issue?